# extract domain subdomain from spf record with php regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, dns, subdomain, spf

I want to extract the subdomain & domain name from an spf record using the regex php.

```
$spfreccord= ' v=spf1 include:smtproutes.com include:smtpout.com ip4:46.163.100.196 ip4:46.163.100.194 ip4:85.13.135.76 ip4:178.255.156.110 ip4:188.172.204.21 ip4:178.255.154.52 ip4:188.172.233.6 ip4:37.252.230.29 ip4:217.146.22.37 ~all';
spfreccord2="v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all";
$regexdomain = '/\s*([-a-z0-9]+\.)+' . implode("|", $extensionList) . '\s*/i';
preg_match_all($regexdomain, $spfreccord,$matchesdom);
// echo the result



foreach ($matchesdom as $ke) {
foreach ($ke as $domspf) {

    echo $domspf;
    echo "<br>";
}
}
```

what kind of regex should i use to extract simple domain & subdomain like _netblocks.google.com

Comment: Don't try to match the whole thing with a regex. Keep it simple, read the RFC spec. The record is space-delimited, so do that first, then deal with the various prefixes before you get to the domains. It would not surprise me if you could find a class to do this already - look on packagist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't clearly get what you are asking. But here what I think you need:

```
$spfreccord ='v=spf1 include:smtproutes.com include:smtpout.com ip4:46.163.100.196 ip4:46.163.100.194 ip4:85.13.135.76 ip4:178.255.156.110 ip4:188.172.204.21 ip4:178.255.154.52 ip4:188.172.233.6 ip4:37.252.230.29 ip4:217.146.22.37 ~all';
$spfreccord2 ="v=spf1 include:_netblocks.google.com include:_netblocks2.google.com include:_netblocks3.google.com ~all";

$domainExts = ["com", "net", "org", "io"]; // fill according to your needs

$regex = "/:([\w]*?)\\.?([\w]*?)\\.(".implode("|", $domainExts).")/";

preg_match_all($regex, $spfreccord2, $output);
// $output[1] => Subdomains.
// $output[2] => Domains
// $output[3] => Domain extension

var_dump($output);
/*
array(4) {
  [0] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(22) ":_netblocks.google.com"
    [1] =>
    string(23) ":_netblocks2.google.com"
    [2] =>
    string(23) ":_netblocks3.google.com"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(10) "_netblocks"
    [1] =>
    string(11) "_netblocks2"
    [2] =>
    string(11) "_netblocks3"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) "google"
    [1] =>
    string(6) "google"
    [2] =>
    string(6) "google"
  }
  [3] =>
  array(3) {
    [0] =>
    string(3) "com"
    [1] =>
    string(3) "com"
    [2] =>
    string(3) "com"
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: This what i'm looking for thank you @Samed, it work for me fine.
you just need to remve the ":"  twodots from the regex pattern & it will be like this.
`$regex = "/([\w]*?)\\.?([\w]*?)\\.(".implode("|", $domainExts).")/";`

Answer (score -1):

```
      preg_match_all('/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(.*?)[\.][a-zA-Z]{1,3}(.*?)/',$str_search,$arr,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
print_r($arr);
```

Domain:$arr[0][0];
Subdomain:$arr[2][0];

Comment: i've try your regex pattern but it cause me a small problem, without any output.
Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: the print_r have empty array, the regex didn't extract any domain from the string.
`array(4) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } [3]=> array(0) { } }`

Comment: This pattern is completely useless. It appears to be trying to match URLs, which have absolutely nothing to do with this question.

Comment: yes that's true @Syncro, it didn't solve the problem.
but i think the answer of Samed  solve this questions.